# Set focus to control after show modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need to set focus on a control inside the modal after the show modal event.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$('#searcherCustomerModal').on('shown', function () {
    $("#txtNameCustomer").select();
});
```

But it does not work. Any Ideas?

Comment: Why is there `knockout.js` tag?

Comment: I'm making the development using knockout.js ... I will remove it...

Comment: Fixed, I have found the solution in this question !! : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634809/twitter-bootstrap-focus-on-textarea-inside-a-modal-on-click) .. `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#textareaID').focus();
})`

Comment: @FreddyCastelblancoMacias you should post your answer and accept it so future users can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery, you set focus with [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) not [`.select()`](http://api.jquery.com/select/)
Also, in Bootstrap 3, the shown event is called [`shown.bs.modal`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

So the code should look like this:

```
$('#searcherCustomerModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#txtNameCustomer").focus();
});
```

**Demo in Stack Snippets**:

```js
$('#searcherCustomerModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#txtNameCustomer").focus();
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#searcherCustomerModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="searcherCustomerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="txtNameCustomer" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```